# how to show insert update messages on same page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I am inserting or updating data in Codeigniter I want to show a message whether data is inserted or updated my message is already showing in controller but I want to show it on view page. And I don't want to redirect during update and insertion.

**here is my update time code in Controller i.e. showing message**.

```
if($result)
    {
            $this->load->view('includes/header');
            $this->load->view('includes/menu');
            echo "<div class='success'>";
            echo "Successfully Updated";
            echo "</div>";

            redirect(current_url());

     }
    else 
    {

            $this->load->view('includes/header');
            $this->load->view('includes/menu');
            echo "<div class='error'>";
            echo "Somthins Is Missing";
            echo "</div>";

     }
```

I also want to know I am using `redirect(current_url());` is it correct or without using it we can generate message from controller to view.

Comment: if u don't want to redirect means you have to use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can send any data to view like

```
$data['msg']='Message inserted successfully';

 $this->load->view('includes/header',$data); //send data like this
```

Then retrieve it in view
directly like

```
echo "<div class='success'> $msg   </div>";
```

Comment: it showing an error on view page  **Undefined variable: msg**

Comment: no i write if($result) {  $data['msg']='Message inserted successfully';
            $this->load->view('form',$data);  }

Comment: are you `echo $msg` in form.php view file??

Comment: I think after loading the views, you are again redirecting, check it

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "flash message". Basically, the message(s) are being stored in a session variable. This way you can redirect in your controller, but your view still knows about the message. Search the web for "codeigniter flash message".